# Chart.js time series showing empty plot

Tags: javascript, chart.js

This is the code I'm using to display the chart

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <script>
    var data1 = [{
        x: new Date("2020-01-01 18:00:00"),
        y: 1
    }, {
        x: new Date("2020-01-02 18:00:00"),
        y: 2
    },{
        x: new Date("2020-01-03 18:00:00"),
        y: 3
  }];
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    console.log(data1);
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data1,
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day'
                    },
                    distribution: 'linear',
                }]
            }
        }
    });


    </script>
```

I've tried pasting a typical chart.js example from their website and the chart is displayed just fine. I have also tried using a string in the x-axis but that doesn't seem to work as well

Can't figure out why this is happening, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not able to get your question here. Also, where did you copy this code from? This code is wrong at first only as you are not using `getContext('2d')` to get the `ctx`.

Answer (score 0):

As [palaѕн](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823841/pala%D1%95%D0%BD) commented, you don't correctly retrieve the 2D-Context. This should look as follows.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
```

Further the data object needs to be defined in a different way.

```
data: {
  datasets: [{
    data: data1
  }]
},
```

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
var data1 = [{
  x: new Date("2020-01-01 18:00:00"),
  y: 1
}, {
  x: new Date("2020-01-02 18:00:00"),
  y: 2
}, {
  x: new Date("2020-01-03 18:00:00"),
  y: 3
}];

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',  
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: data1
    }]
  },
  data1,
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        },
        distribution: 'linear',
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="120"></canvas>
```